# Author Archive Page redirecting issue

Tags: redirect, archives, author

When I click "Author" Hyperlink anywhere on the website, It is not working.

say, I click: `https://digitalvarys.com/author/admin/`

And It Redirects to `http://admin/`

Why is it?

Refer the Network:

[image]

Comment: Deactivate all plugins, switch to a default theme, update permalinks, then check the page again.

Comment: @Shazzad Not Working! First deactivated all plugin, then changed the theme to all. It remains same. Seems like! Problem with Core Wordpress! Is there any possiblity that corrupt core wordpress code